# Second inner join doubles count result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables A, B and C. A has many B and C. For A I have 6 B records and half of them are marked as deleted (deleted_at != null).

When I select with query

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE a.id = 5;
```

answer is correct (id: 5, count: 3)

But when I add one more inner join

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(b.id)
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.deleted_at IS NULL
INNER JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.a_id AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE a.id = 5;
```

it doubles count result (id:5, count: 6)

How can I fix it?

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) ??

Comment: Give sample table data, it would be better to analyze the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As othered have mentioned you can count distinct b IDs here.

However, your problem is quite common when one needs aggregates from various tables. The problems occur, because people join all records and then try to get the aggregates.

For instance:

```
SELECT a.id, SUM(b.value)
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.deleted_at IS NULL
INNER JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.a_id AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE a.id = 5;
```

This is almost the same query as yours. But here you cannot use DISTINCT anymore, because if you had values 100, 200, 200 in b, you would get 300 instead of 500 then. So the *general* solution is: Only join what actually shall be joined. Here are two solutions for above query:

Solution 1: Aggregate before you join:

```
SELECT a.id, b.total
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN 
(
   select a_id, sum(value) as total 
   from table_b 
   where deleted_at IS NULL
   group by a_id
) b ON a.id = b.a_id
INNER JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.a_id AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE a.id = 5;
```

Solution 2: If you only need one value from a table, get it in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT a.id, 
(
   select sum(value)
   from table_b 
   where deleted_at IS NULL
   and a_id = a.id
)  as total 
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.a_id AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE a.id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could count distinct values

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)
FROM table_a a 
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.deleted_at IS NULL
INNER JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.a_id AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
WHERE a.id = 5;
```

Comment: The second solution is wrong. You can still have many `c` for one `a` and thus multiply the count.

Comment: Thorsten you are right - I have removed the second solution

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I have started programming.
I dont know exactly that you also are facing the same issue or not.

If table_c has more then one matching coulmns with other two tables i.e. with table_a & table_b
then you will need to add another condition in the the `ON clause`.

**Example :**

If suppose 
table_a consist of

```
ID   |    Name  |   Secondary_id
```

table_b consist of

```
ID   |    Some other coulmn |
```

table_a consist of

```
ID   |    Some coulmn  |   Secondary_id
```

Then in this case your third table ie `table_c` will have two same coulmns as in `table_a`

then

you will now have to write the query like this.

```
select * from
table_a 
JOIN tablE_b ON  table_a.ID = table_b.ID
JOIN tablE_c ON  tablE_c.ID = table_b.ID and table_a.Secondary_id = table_b.Secondary_id
```

note that I have added two condition in the `ON clause`

```
ON  tablE_c.ID = table_b.ID and table_a.Secondary_id = table_b.Secondary_id
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: @Sergei Gorjunov I am not completely sure that you will have the same issue but you may also facing the same issue